# Vectorized code slower than loops? MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, loops, vectorization

In the problem Im working on there is such a part of code, as shown below. The definition part is just to show you the sizes of arrays. Below I pasted vectorized version - and it is >2x slower. Why it happens so? I know that i happens if vectorization requiers large temporary variables, but (it seems) it is not true here.

And generally, what (other than parfor, with I already use) can I do to speed up this code?

```
maxN = 100;  
levels = maxN+1;  
xElements = 101;  
umn = complex(zeros(levels, levels));  
umn2 = umn;  
bessels = ones(xElements, xElements, levels);    % 1.09 GB  
posMcontainer = ones(xElements, xElements, maxN);  

tic  
for j = 1 : xElements  
    for i = 1 : xElements  
        for n = 1 : 2 : maxN  
            nn = n + 1;  
            mm = 1;  
            for m = 1 : 2 : n  
                umn(nn, mm) = bessels(i, j, nn) * posMcontainer(i, j, m);  
                mm = mm + 1;  
            end  
        end  
    end  
end  
toc % 0.520594 seconds  


tic  
for j = 1 : xElements  
    for i = 1 : xElements  
        for n = 1 : 2 : maxN  
            nn = n + 1;  
            m = 1:2:n;  
            numOfEl = ceil(n/2);  
            umn2(nn, 1:numOfEl) = bessels(i, j, nn) * posMcontainer(i, j, m);  
        end  
    end  
end  
toc % 1.275926 seconds  

sum(sum(umn-umn2)) % veryfying, if all done right
```

Best regards,
Alex

From the profiler:

[image: from Profiler]

**Edit:**

In reply to [@Jason answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39186883/2627163), this alternative takes the same time:

```
for n = 1:2:maxN  
    nn(n) = n + 1;  
    numOfEl(n) = ceil(n/2);  
end  

for j = 1 : xElements  
    for i = 1 : xElements  
        for n = 1 : 2 : maxN  
            umn2(nn(n), 1:numOfEl(n)) = bessels(i, j, nn(n)) * posMcontainer(i, j, 1:2:n);  
        end  
    end  
end
```

**Edit2**:
In reply to @EBH :
The point is to do the following:

```
parfor i = 1 : xElements  
    for j = 1 : xElements  
    umn = complex(zeros(levels, levels)); % cleaning  
    for n = 0:maxN
        mm = 1;
        for m = -n:2:n
            nn = n + 1; % for indexing

            if m < 0
                umn(nn, mm) = bessels(i, j, nn) * negMcontainer(i, j, abs(m));
            end

            if m > 0
                umn(nn, mm) = bessels(i, j, nn) * posMcontainer(i, j, m);
            end

            if m == 0
                umn(nn, mm) = bessels(i, j, nn);
            end

            mm = mm + 1; % for indexing
        end % m
    end % n
    beta1 = sum(sum(Aj1.*umn));
    betaSumSq1(i, j) = abs(beta1).^2;

    beta2 = sum(sum(Aj2.*umn));
    betaSumSq2(i, j) = abs(beta2).^2;
    end % j
end % i
```

I speeded it up as much, as I was able to. What you have written is taking only the last `bessels` and `posMcontainer` values, so it does not produce the same result. In the real code, those two containers are filled not with `1`, but with some precalculated values.

Comment: strange: what happens if you write "posMcontainer(i, j, 1:2:n)" instead?
or, alternatively,
"umn2(nn, :) = posMcontainer(i, j, 1:2:n);  umn2(nn, :) = umn2(nn, :) * bessels(i,j,nn)" ?

Comment: The 1st trick makes the vectorized code a bit faster, in deed. But still 2x slower, than loops. The second trick is not working: "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch."

Comment: ok, sorry, what about "umn2(nn, 1:numOfEl) = posMcontainer(i, j, 1:2:n); umn2(nn, 1:numOfEl) = umn2(nn, 1:numOfEl) * bessels(i,j,nn)"?

Comment: It gets almost 2x slower

Comment: Your code can probably be fully vectorized (i.e. none to one `for` loops), and this will make it much faster. But to get help with that you need to explain your goal, because right now it seem weird that you delete and replace the elements in `umn` for every `i` and `j`, you could just run it with `bessels(xElements,xElements, nn) * posMcontainer(xElements,xElements,m)`...

Comment: Is `negMcontainer` is the same size as `posMcontainer`? and what are `Aj1` and `Aj2`?

Comment: Yes, same size. Aj1 and Aj2 are complex random numbers - they simulate randomness in the e-m filed. Size for both of them is 101x101 complex double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your edit, I can see that `umn` is just a temporary variable for another calculation. It still can be mostly vectorizable:

```
betaSumSq1 = zeros(xElements); % preallocating
betaSumSq2 = zeros(xElements); % preallocating
% an index matrix to fetch the right values from negMcontainer and
% posMcontainer:
indmat = tril(repmat([0 1;1 0],ceil((maxN+1)/2),floor(levels/2)));
indmat(end,:) = [];
% an index matrix to fetch the values in correct order for umn:
b_ind = repmat([1;0],ceil((maxN+1)/2),1);
b_ind(end) = [];
tempind = logical([fliplr(indmat) b_ind indmat+triu(ones(size(indmat)))]);

% permute the arrays to prevent squeeze:
PM = permute(posMcontainer,[3 1 2]);
NM = permute(negMcontainer,[3 1 2]);
B = permute(bessels,[3 1 2]);

for k = 1 : maxN+1 % third dim
    for jj = 1 : xElements % columns
        b = B(:,jj,k); % get one vector of B

        % perform b*NM for every row of NM*indmat, than flip the result:
        neg = fliplr(bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@times,indmat,NM(:,jj,k).'),b));

        % perform b*PM for every row of PM*indmat:
        pos = bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@times,indmat,PM(:,jj,k).'),b);

        temp = [neg mod(1:levels,2).'.*b pos].'; % concat neg and pos
        % assign them to the right place in umn:
        umn = reshape(temp(tempind.'),[levels levels]).';

        beta1 = Aj1.*umn;
        betaSumSq1(jj,k) = abs(sum(beta1(:))).^2;
        beta2 = Aj2.*umn;
        betaSumSq2(jj,k) = abs(sum(beta2(:))).^2;
    end
end
```

This reduce running time from **~95** seconds to less **3** seconds (both without `parfor`), so it improves in almost **97%**.

Comment: Thanx. I edited again my post to show you the code. I do not understad, why you take only the last values in bessels and posMcontainer? In the real code every value in those 2 containers is different (not just ones). It would be great to vectorize the code completly, but I dont know, how to do this.

Comment: @Aleksander read my edit to the answer, for your first code, it doesn't matter what are the elements in `bessels` or `posMcontainer`.

Comment: Yes, in the full code u_{mn} are the simulated electromagnetic modes of light, and betaSumSq1 and betaSumSq2 are the images drawn using them. The point is to get betaSumSq1 and betaSumSq2, no matter how.

Comment: betaSumSq1 and betaSumSq2 are kind of images, they are 2D and both has the size of 1:xElement, so:  betaSumSq1 = zeros(xElements, xElements);. With parfor and after compiling, your code runs 56 sec. The original 52 sec. Strange, maybe I included it in a wrong way, I will work on it more

Comment: `betaSumSq1 = zeros(xElements, xElements);` is the same as `betaSumSq1 = zeros(xElements);`, try it, and see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html#btov2gk-2)

Comment: You are right of course, thanx. I ran your vectorized version in realt code and it seems that the problem is an allocation fo temp variable every time. It also changes size every time, and such memory allocation is not recomended in vercorized code (AFAIK). In real code xElements = 1201; and it stops to be faster. I will try to modeify your code to avoid memory allocation every loop, it should help.

Comment: @Aleksander Well, this was only one step in this way, the goal is to get rid of all the `for` loops, or all but one. I knew I won't have time to do it all right now, but I wanted you to see the first step, so you can think of it meanwhile. I'll edit my answer a soon as I'll progress with that. BTW, have you tried testing it without `parfor`?

Comment: I just tried without parfor, it got slower ~3x. Im working on it still, but already I also know, that squeeze() is not helping (I have MAtlab 2016a).

Comment: @Aleksander 1. the more you vectorize the code, the less `parfor` is helpful. 2. see my last edit for another step in vectorizing the loops, now only two are left.

Comment: I just did it. Thank you and Im sorry, I am new here and still learning.I think its a very good idea to use triangular parts of matrix and generally I learned a lot. Now experimenting with your code. So far I am gettin an error "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch" in umn2(n,1:n) = nonzeros(temp(n,:)).'; , but I will handle this. The full code is here BTW, but it is 3,2 GB of data (precoputed containers included): https://www.dropbox.com/s/2n5q9fepi4jlqrf/code.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Aleksander look at my edit, this line do not exist anymore.

Comment: @Aleksander Well, I have just edited the answer for the last time, I don't think you can make it much faster. I also added some notes in the code to help you understand what each part does. My suggestion is that you try to test and understand this on a small sample of the data, and only when you 100% sure it works fine - run it on all the data (and accept the answer to notify the system that the problem was solved).

Comment: Thanx again. I know what happens. If there are zeros in negMcontainer, the code hangs and say: In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same. It happens in this line: umntemp(umnind) = nonzeros(temp.');. I will try to solve it somehow

Comment: @Aleksander I have updated the answer to correct that (with `tempind`), and now it's even faster!

Comment: Thanx, I see I would not come to this solution any time soon myself. The code is working and giving correct results. When I make it to produce 1201*1201 image, it is obviously slower, but still faster, than loops. But when I compile it to mex with parfor, it gets ~3x slower, than loops, with is strange. If I remove parfor from this .mex, it gets slower by another ~2.5x, so parfor seems to be recomended. I wonder what happens, since without compilation your code is faster than enything I ever managed to do myself. I will use a few tricks to find out, since profiling is difficult inside .mex`s.

Comment: You better know that all builtin functions in MATLAB are much faster than .mex (they are written in FORTRAN, and don't need all the communication between .mex and .m files). So whenever you can - use them. .mex usually has an advantage when you have large loops with a lot of statements. A similar argument is true for `parfor`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect it is memory allocation. You are re-allocating the `m` array in a 3 deep loop.
try rearranging the code:

```
tic
for n = 1 : 2 : maxN
    nn = n + 1;
    m = 1:2:n;
    numOfEl = ceil(n/2);
    for j = 1 : xElements
        for i = 1 : xElements
            umn2(nn, 1:numOfEl) = bessels(i, j, nn) * posMcontainer(i, j, m);
        end
    end
end
toc % 1.275926 seconds
```

I was trying this in Igor pro, which a similar language, but with different optimizations. So the direct translations don't time the same way as Matlab (vectorized was slightly faster in Igor).  But reordering the loops did speed up the vectorized form.

In your second part of the code, that is setting `umn2`, inside the loops, you have:

```
nn = n + 1;  
m = 1:2:n;  
numOfEl = ceil(n/2);
```

Those 3 lines don't require any input from the `i` and `j` loops, they only use the `n` loop. So reordering the loops such that `i` and `j` are inside the `n` loop will mean that those 3 lines are done `xElements^2` (100^2) times less often.  I suspect it is that `m = 1:2:n` line that takes time, since that is allocating an array.

Comment: Thanx. m = 1:2:n takes time, but only 0.2 sec. So, when I do the indexing of posMcontainer like this: posMcontainer(i, j, 1:2:n), it is getting 0.2 sec faster, but still 2x slower, than loops. Strange, I would guess, that it should help more